# Performance implications with views and indices

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table foo:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
    FOO_ID INTEGER,
    STATUS INTEGER,
    RATING INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY ("FOO_ID")
)
```

where status can be between 0 and 5, and the table is filled with rows.

Let's then say I create an index on the status, and another on rating:

```
CREATE INDEX ON FOO (STATUS);
CREATE INDEX ON FOO (RATING);
```

Now, suppose I have a view:

```
CREATE VIEW FOO_THREE_VIEW AS
  SELECT * 
  FROM FOO
  WHERE STATUS = 3;
```

I want to get the records in foo that are: `STATUS = 3` and `RATING = 5`. The following query would give me the results I want:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE STATUS = 3 AND RATING = 5;
```

But, the following query would ALSO give me the results I want:

```
SELECT * FROM FOO_THREE_VIEW WHERE RATING = 5;
```

Of the two queries, is there a performance difference? 
Does the first query benefit from both of the indices? Does the second query benefit from both the indices? I can't create an index on the view to help with the performance, correct? How would the performance of the two change if there was an index on both of the columns, like `CREATE INDEX ON FOO (STATUS, RATING)` instead of two separate indices?

I understand that the question can be a general SQL question, but when needing specification, I'd like to know how it works specifically in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be no performance *(and in this case also execution)* difference. Which of the indexes will be used depends on the data and statistics, just use `EXPLAIN` to check which index is preferred by the database. In the described case index on 2 columns will be most suitable.

You cannot create indexes on the views, as PostgreSQL treats and stores views as a plain `SQL` statements. When you issue query against view, internally, query is rewritten and transformed before planning starts. You can read more on how PostgreSQL processes your requests [in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/overview.html). This will change for the [Materialized Views](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views), which are currently being actively developed.

Also you can always use [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html) to inspect *how* this or that query will be processed and compare execution plans for the cases with and without view involved.